# GOF Logistic model R

Tags: r, design-patterns

I want to extract individual statistics from the R output below. How to do?

```
# R code
library(pscl)
full <- glm(RESPONSE ~ as.factor(SEX) + TOTCHOL + AGE + ..., 
        data=training, family=binomial(link="logit"))
summary(full)
# McFadden's GOF pseudo R-squared, 0.2 to 0.4 indicates good model fit
McFadden=round(pR2(full),digits=4)['McFadden']; McFadden
```

Output:

```
 library(pscl)
 round(pR2(reduced),digits=4)
      llh   llhNull        G2  McFadden      r2ML   r2CU
-165.6085 -191.1523   51.0875    0.1336    0.0663   0.1651
```

Error:

```
pR2$McFadden
Error in pR2$McFadden : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you didn't give us all the code and that `reduced` was assigned the values of a regression call and appears to be a vector rather than a list, so you would (probably) use something like this untested code:

```
round(pR2(reduced),digits=4)['McFadden']
```

Comment: I have never used this kind of syntax that is ['McFadden']. Thank you very much. It works... MM